# Most effective instant access savings for a child - UK

Tags: united-kingdom, savings, children

We have a maxed out stocks and shares ISA for our baby - what is the most effective non-term limited account that can be in her name? We're thinking it will be useful for birthday parties, clothes etc. Most of the payments will be on an ad-hoc basis from gifts etc.

Comment: http://www.moneysavingexpert.com/savings/child-savings-tax-free

Comment: What do you mean by 'effective' ?

Comment: Hmmm...I guess I mean tax effective, easy to open & access, and (if possible), good rates of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Just get the child whatever deposit account you can find. There won't be any tax on the interest unless:

- there is more than £100/year of interest on money that came from you (her parents), as opposed to grandparents, friends, other relatives etc.
- there is more than the personal allowance (>£10K/year) of any interest

If you're just saving for parties, clothes etc it's unlikely you'll hit either limit.

https://www.gov.uk/savings-for-children